# Open info layer together with click on marker (leaflet)

Tags: leaflet

I would like to trigger an extra event when clicking on a marker. Now, it opens a popup, but instead I would like to show the information in an extra info layer. I have managed to show the layer (var info), but I don't know how to change the information with a click on the marker.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Schönberg Topography</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/mapbox.css" />
  <script src="../lib/mapbox.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
  <script src="../dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
  <script charset="UTF-8" src="topography.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .info {
      padding: 6px 8px;
      font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background: white;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .info h4 {
      margin: 0 0 5px;
      color: #777;
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
    a:link {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      cloudmadeAttribution = 'Map data &copy; 2011 <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery &copy; 2011 <a href="http://mapbox.com/" target="_blank">Mapbox</a>, Points &copy 2012 <a href="http://linz.govt.nz/" target="_blank">LINZ</a>',
      cloudmade = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {
        maxZoom: 17,
        attribution: cloudmadeAttribution
      }),
      latlng = new L.LatLng(48.86, 2.34);

    var map = new L.Map('map', {
      center: latlng,
      zoom: 12,
      maxBounds: [
        [49, 2.7],
        [48.7, 2, 45]
      ],
      layers: [cloudmade]
    });

    var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

    for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
      var a = addressPoints[i];
      var title = a[2];
      var name = a[3]
      var colormarker = a[4]
      var typemarker = a[5]
      var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
        icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          'marker-symbol': typemarker,
          'marker-color': colormarker
        }),
        title: name
      });

      var info = L.control();

      info.onAdd = function() {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
        this.update();
        return this._div;
      };

      // method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
      info.update = function() {
        this._div.innerHTML = title;
      };

      marker.bindPopup(title);
      markers.addLayer(marker);

    }

    map.addLayer(markers);
    info.addTo(map);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify your `update` function to take a parameter to begin here.You also only need to be creating this info control once, not each time inside the loop..because you only need one open at a time, right?

```
  info.update = function(content) {
    this._div.innerHTML = content;
  };
```

Don't forget to update your `onAdd` with regards to removing the `update`.

```
  info.onAdd = function() {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    return this._div;
  };
```

Then, inside the callback for a `click` event on a marker, you would call `info.update("My new content")`.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't succeed - probably because of too limited coding abilities ... I can see my info layer, but I can't connect it with the click on the marker. Maybe it would help to replace <marker.bindPopup(title);> with something else?

Comment: Sure - here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/euxxznjd/
And here is the actual map: http://www.schoenberg.at/scans/topo-paris/example/topo-paris.html
I succeded to show the info layer with a click. But the content is always the same, and the info layers just get more and more.

Comment: `this.update();` is still in it's place, because whenever I removed it, I saw no info layer at all.